# Google Composer Dag not triggered Automatically or even via CMD

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow

Below is my simple DAG/ Python script that is inside the DAGS folder on Google cloud bucket .

```
from airflow import DAG
import airflow
from airflow.operators import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime,timedelta , date 

from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from generate_csv_feeds import generate_csv

DEFAULT_DAG_ARGS = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime.utcnow(),
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'schedule_interval':'*/5 * * * *'
}

with DAG('DAG_MAIN',default_args=DEFAULT_DAG_ARGS,catchup=False) as dag:

    generate_csv = PythonOperator(
        task_id='generate_mktg_csv',
        python_callable=generate_csv,
        op_args=['get_data.sql','feeds_data_airflow.csv']
    )    

    csv_generated = BashOperator(
        task_id='csv_generated',
        bash_command='echo CSV Generated Succesfully.')

    generate_csv >> csv_generated
```

The issue is that it does not get triggered automatically at all nor does it get executed if i trigger it externally via the Command line. But strangely it works when i run it from the Airflow UI . I need this to run every 5 minutes . I am not sure if this has anything to do with Google Composer. Any help would be appreciated . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is due to your `start_date` being `datetime.utcnow()`. It is not recommended to use moving `start_date` especially `datetime.utcnow()` because the DAG is triggered at `start_date + schedule_interval` and as the `start_date` is moving, the DAG is never triggered. See the FAQ https://airflow.apache.org/faq.html#what-s-the-deal-with-start-date.

Try with a fixed `start_date` like `datetime(2019, 08, 04)`.